# ember EmbeddedRecordsMixin

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### adapters/foodoption.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function (modelType, id) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080/getData' ;
  },
  handleResponse: function(status, headers, payload) {
   payload = {foodoptions: payload};
   return this._super(status, headers, payload);
  }
});
```

### models/foodoption.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    responsetype: DS.attr(),
    responselists:DS.hasMany('responselist', { embedded: 'always' })
});
```

### models/responselist.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    description: DS.attr(),
    deleted:DS.attr()
});
```

### serializers/foodoption.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    responselists: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

### Response from server:

```
{  
   "id":100,
   "responsetype":"FOOD",
   "responselist":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "description":"One",
         "deleted":"N"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "description":"Two",
         "deleted":"N"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "description":"Three",
         "deleted":"N"
      }
   ]
}
```

Question: when I do this.store.findAll('foodoption'), only responsetype is loaded in model, responselist are not loaded from server response.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think there's a typo in your models/foodoption.js: responselists instead of responselist(see your server payload)

Comment: Thank you @wuarmin,  this solved my problem